# CSS Modules not working as expected in tests with Jest and Enzyme, using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-css-modules

I am using CSS modules in a CRA app. My component looks like this:

```js
import HeaderStyles from './Header.module.scss';

const Header: FunctionComponent<HeaderProps> = ({
// Props
}) => (
  <div className={HeaderStyles['header-container']}>
  // Some other stuff
)
```

My test looks like this:

```js
    const component = shallow(
      <Header />
    );

    expect(component.find('.header-container')).toBeTruthy();
```

I would expect it to fail since the class name should be something different since I'm using CSS Modules. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I researched and found that either jest or react-scripts are loading just an empty object instead of that style module. I guess that they use another loader or something, but that's kind of cool as in unit testing, you need to test only your part of packages or loaders and not how other packages work, so that's fine.

The strange thing is that any intern would start by querying `HeaderStyles['header-container']`, leading to an invalid test and would take much more time.

So my suggestion is to switch to using [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles), which is much more declarative and removes strangeness from tests. With PatchStyles, you need to change your code to

```
<PatchStyles classNames={HeaderStyles}>
  <div className="header-container">...</div>
</PatchStyles>
```

and it'll automatically apply HeaderStyles instead of you. For more info, take a look at the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-patch-styles?file=src/pages/FirstPage.module.css) example.